# Permissions issue with new team site

Tags: 2007, permissions

I have a team site within a team site.

In the top level team site I am in the owners group.

In the second level team site I have full control, but I'm not in the owners group.

In the top level group I can add people to the Members and Owners groups. In the second level site I cannot.

If I click on Groups:More... then click on the edit icon next to the Owners or Members group I get the following message:

> Only owners of the group "AP Intra -
>   VN Members" can change its settings.

Considering I have full access; why can't I access these groups?

How can I get access and how can I change permissions so that I can add new users to both of these groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Site Actions > Site Settings > People and Groups > AP Intra - VN Members (in Quick Launch)
- Settings > Group Settings
- Make note of the Group owner
- Modify "Who can edit the membership of the group?" to Group Members
- Add yourself to the group that is listed as the Group owner
- Go back and modify "Who can edit the membership of the group?" back to Group owner

Comment: @Laurie - I don't have the 'Group Settings' option on the second level site, but I do have it on the parent.

Comment: Can you view the Owners group in the subsite and see who is in that group? Then someone in that group could add you.

Comment: @Laurie - If I try to open AP Intra - VN Owners I get the following: 'You do not have permission to view the membership of the group.'. Thanks for your help.

Comment: But if I look at:  
AP Intra - Vietnam > Site Settings > Permissions   it has me listed as Full Control. Also there is another group AP Intra - Vietnam Owners which has me as the only member. I did not create any of these groups they were created at the time I created the sub site.

Comment: It sounds like the groups you want are Vietnam Owners and Vietnam Members. Can you just ignore the other ones? Maybe someone else added the new groups (VN Owners and VN Members) to the subsite?

Comment: Laurie - Not possible because we have a small IT team and nobody uses this SharePoint site. I have settled for now on creating a group in the parent site and giving that group permission to contribute on the sub-site. If I click on the More... link it doesn't show any Vietnam Owners and Vietnam Members groups. Considering this is just a dev site I will see how I go when moving to production and hope it doesn't happen there. Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Was that group created when the site was provisioned?  If you can't edit the permissions of it that means someone else created it and by default that is the only person who can modify the membership of the group.  The group creator needs to edit the properties of the group so that the owner group is listed as the group owner.

Comment: I created the second team site, not the parent. I only created it a few days ago so nobody else has touched it. The groups were created by default when the new site was created. I assumed that I should be the creator of the groups.